# Windows Azure notification hub, my app doesn't receive notifications

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

My application doesn't seem to receive the notifications i send to it, using the debug mode inside the azure site, sending test notifications, i allso tried sending the notifications through some .net code which didn't work either, seems like my notification hub is receiveing these notifications but my application on the phone is not, internet is running, usb-debugging is on, and im not getting the logs that says "herpderp notification received".

i have successfully registered my app in the notification hub, and is awaiting response with the following code:

```
  gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String connectionString = "***THIS IS where my connection string is, and it doesn't contain errors";
    hub = new NotificationHub("denlillemandhub", connectionString, this);
    NotificationsManager.handleNotifications(this, SENDER_ID, MyHandler.class);
    registerWithGcm();
```

the registerWithGcm() method:

```
 private void registerWithGcm() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                Log.i(TAG, "Registered with id: " + registrationId);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            Log.d("Done", "attempt to register was done loading");
            /**lblRegistration.setText(mRegistrationId);
            lblStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.status_registered)); */
        };
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

MyHandler class(that i give the notificationHandler as parameter):

```
 import com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsHandler;
  public class MyHandler extends NotificationsHandler
  {
  public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
  Context ctx;

   @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
    ctx = context;
    String nhMessage = bundle.getString("msg");
    Log.d("line 27", "onReceive");
    sendNotification(nhMessage);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("line 32", "sendNotification");
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            new Intent(ctx, ToDoActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification Hub Demo")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

and last(my androidManifest just the show permissions):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.denlillemand.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.denlillemand.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<receiver android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="com.example.denlillemand" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My surgestion is to assume that my scripting on the server side is correct, and that the 
my GCM / Azure API keys/settings are all correct.   Obviously my Notification hub receives as it's suppose to, but it seems that GCM either doesn't deliver to the registered device, or that the device does get the notification, but doesn't handle it correctly.

I would thank any1 who would want to read through all this to give a qualifed guess a HUGE thanks, ive really been struggleing with this.

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem

Comment: Sorry m8, it was too hard to debug. Suddenly my friend just got it working, and he basically didn't change anything, so that is really demotivating, he couldn't give me an answer back then i remember. My best suggestion is to go carefully through the documentation, make sure you have your internet switched on the phone and stupid little things like that. Other wise i would post a question here detailing your exact situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **registerWithGcm()** method after lines

```
registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
Log.i(TAG, "Registered with id: " + registrationId);
```

add this:

```
hub.register(registrationId);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, ive added that line of code 1 day after i wrote this. And it still didn't work. the weirdest thing is that this exact code + the hub.register(registrationId); works with another project of mine. But i dumped this project, it's simply too much code to go through to find the mistake, Azure server,the notificationhub, c# code, java code, the xml and the GCM. So im sorry but i cannot add the reason for why it suddenly works for any1 who's looking for answers. i hope my example code might help some1 trying to figuire it out.